# Python urllib urlopen not working

Tags: python, urllib

I am just trying to fetch data from a live web by using the urllib module, so I wrote a simple example

Here is my code:

```
import urllib

sock = urllib.request.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print (htmlSource)
```

But I got error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sock = urllib.request.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/") 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are reading the wrong documentation or the wrong Python interpreter version. You tried to use the Python 3 library in Python 2.

Use:

```
import urllib2

sock = urllib2.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print htmlSource
```

The Python 2 [`urllib2` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) was replaced by [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

```
import requests
import urllib

link = "http://www.somesite.com/details.pl?urn=2344"

f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()

writeFileObj = open('output.xml', 'wb')
writeFileObj.write(myfile)
writeFileObj.close()
```

Comment: Usually a good answer doesn't contain just code but a little information on what exactly got fixed.

Comment: isn't requests an different module that you're not actually using in this answer?

Answer (score 6):

In **Python3** you can use **urllib** or **urllib3**

urllib:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://docs.python.org') as response:
    htmlSource = response.read()
```

urllib3:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://docs.python.org')
htmlSource = r.data
```

More details could be found in the [urllib](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html) or [python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i use to get data from urls, its nice because you could save the file at the same time if you need it:

```
import urllib

result = urllib.urlretrieve("http://diveintopython.org/")

print open(result[0]).read()
```

output:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html><body style="padding:0; margin:0;"><iframe src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/pKMcpaMuM2WwoTq1LzRhLzI0" style="visibility: visible;height: 2000px;" allowtransparency="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe></body></html>'
```

Edit: urlretrieve works in python 2 and 3

Comment: `urlretrieve` is available on Python 3 as well as part of the [legacy interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface). If all you wanted was the data *in memory*, then `urlretrieve` is the wrong tool; you downloaded the data to disk then opened it again from the file.

Comment: Moreover, this doesn't even attempt to answer the question stated.

Comment: well i stated that urlretrieve is nice because you can save the file ... thats the whole point. if someone tells me he wants to fetch data from the internet why not suggesting something like that.

Comment: and i didnt know that it works in python 3 ;-) though it is outdated or something

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import `requests` from `urllib`, then try this format, it worked for me:

```
from urllib import request
urllib.request.urlopen( )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just queried the same question which is now over 5 years old.

Please note that the URL given is also old, so i substituted the *python welcome page*.

We can use the **requests module** in **python 3**.

I use *python 3* and the solution is below:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.python.org/')
t = r.text

print(t)
```

This works and is clean.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3 the correct way should be:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/logo_2.png')
arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1) # 'Load it as it is'

cv2.imshow('image_name', img)
if cv2.waitKey() & 0xff == 27: quit()
```

Here you can find the documentation related to [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Use this**

```py
    import cv2
    import  numpy as np
    import urllib //import urllib using pip
    import requests // import requests using pip`enter code here`
    url = "write your url"
    while True:
    imgresp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgnp = np.array(bytearray(imgresp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgnp,-1)
    cv2.imshow("test",img)
    cv2.waitKey('q')
```

Comment: Please try to correctly format your code if you're posting an answer - this isn't readable. Also, it doesn't really seem like you're addressing the question; you're using numpy, which isn't mentioned in the question, then seem to have some commented-out imports, and finally it seems to be an image you're downloading, which again isn't what the question asks for.