# python read file from a web URL

Tags: python, urllib, readfile

I am currently trying to read a txt file from a website.

My script so far is:

```
webFile = urllib.urlopen(currURL)
```

This way, I can work with the file. However, when I try to store the file (in `webFile`), I only get a link to the socket. Another solution I tried was to use `read()`

```
webFile = urllib.urlopen(currURL).read()
```

However this seems to remove the formating (`\n`, `\t` etc) are removed.

If I open the file like this:

```
 webFile = urllib.urlopen(currURL)
```

I can read it line by line:

```
for line in webFile:
    print line
```

This will should result in:

```
"this" 
"is" 
"a"
"textfile"
```

But I get:

```
't'
'h'
'i'
...
```

I wish to get the file on my computer, but maintain the format at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python. Just take webFile and write it to a file.

Comment: is there no way of doing it, without hving to first write it to a local file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use readlines() to read entire line:

```
response = urllib.urlopen(currURL)
lines = response.readlines()
for line in lines:
    .
    .
```

But, i strongly recommend you to use `requests` library.
Link here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

This is because you iterate over a string. And that will result in character for character printing.

Why not save the whole file at once?

```
import urllib
webf = urllib.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971752/python-read-file-from-web-site-url')
txt = webf.read()

f = open('destination.txt', 'w+')
f.write(txt)
f.close()
```

If you really want to loop over the file line for line use `txt = webf.readlines()` and iterate over that.

Comment: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: I think I wrote this in Python version 2.
See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863101/python-urllib-urlopen-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to save a remote file to your local server as part of a python script, you could use the PycURL library to download and save it without parsing it. More info here - http://pycurl.sourceforge.net

---

Alternatively, if you want to read and then write the output, I think you've just got the methods out of sequence. Try the following:

```
# Assign the open file to a variable
webFile = urllib.urlopen(currURL)

# Read the file contents to a variable
file_contents = webFile.read()
print(file_contents)

> This will be the file contents

# Then write to a new local file
f = open('local file.txt', 'w')
f.write(file_contents)
```

If neither applies, please update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the file and save it using a name that you prefer. After that, you can read the file and later you can delete it if you don't need the file anymore.

```
!pip install wget

import wget 
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/commons-validator/master/src/example/org/apache/commons/validator/example/ValidateExample.java" 
wget.download(url, 'myFile.java')
```