# Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fatal-error, ubuntu-20.04

I try to download an image using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.2/) module in python.It works but when i try to open this image it showing "Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file". [Here](https://pasteboard.co/JhRzO8C.png) is my error screenshot.And the code i used to download is,

```
import requests

img_url = "http://dimik.pub/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/javaWeb.jpg"

r = requests.get(img_url)

with open("java_book.png","wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

And i run my code in terminal just saying, `python3 s.py` (s.py is the name of file).
Is something wrong in my code or something else in my operating system(ubuntu 20.04 LTS)?

Comment: the link returns 404.

Comment: Link working well here.[Here](https://pasteboard.co/JhRHcar.png) is the screenshot.

Comment: I'm getting a webpage from that link.  Are you sure you have the specific link to that specific image?

Comment: Ya,i am sure.I copied link from my code and pasted it on other tab.And i got my image.

Comment: that link is an invalid link to a non-existing file.  That link as provided gives you a webpage of which that picture you're trying to get is just an element of it.  You need to get the exact link to that image.

Comment: Something weird with that URL. It worked once and then stopped working.

Comment: @mpen Agree.Because if i use another URL it's working fine with same code.[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fq9YYKN9tj/) is my code.Actually i am learning web crawling and i made a program to collect all image from specific a webpage,it's working well but when i try to open image, all showing error.[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sc9kjFr4jR/) it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://devnote.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/devnote.png")

file = open("sample_image.png", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
print (response.content)
file.close()
```

https://devnote.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/devnote.png this url is Disable **mod_security**. so this return error like :
`<html><head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>`.

#### Disable mod_security using .htaccess on apache server

Mod_security can be easily disabled with the help of .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you tried to save `javaWeb.jpg` (A `JPG` file) as `java_book.png` (A `PNG` file).

Comment: It's not.If i change this then it showing new error `error interpreting jpeg image file (not a jpeg file starts with 0x3c 0x21)` . [Here](https://pasteboard.co/JhSjS6K.png) is the screenshot.

Comment: Because there's `HTML` for some reason in `r.content`. I just tried it out.

Comment: [This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S9VOQ2ufTs0E1o7i5tn6iRGyJm9-G9722BX7fNsfWqI/edit?usp=sharing) is what I get for `r.content`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your operating system. First you got an error because the image was a JPEG file. And now it's because there's HTML in `r.content`.

Comment: Oh, i understand now.Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This might sound confusing, but you can try: Create a `flask` app; Create an `app.route` at `/book/` and have it return the Java book image; Save the image with `requests`: `requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/book')`.

Comment: BTW, `starts with 0x3c 0x21` means `starts with < !` because, see for yourself: `chr(0x3c), chr(0x21)`.

Comment: And that's true because `HTML` documents start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to see what we are working on, I've tried replicating the issue, please see below what found out.

1.) The file you are attempting to open is the ENTIRE HTML document. I can support this, because we are finding !DOCTYPE html at the beginning of your 'wb' or WRITE BINARY command.

[image: This shows a notepad file what we are working on.]

### <---------------------------------------------- WE ARE AT AN IMPASSE

From here we have a few options to solve our problem.

a.) We could simply download the image from the web page - placing it in a local folder/directory/ or wherever you want it. This is by far our easiest call, because it allows us to call and open it for later without having to do too much. While I'm on a Windows machine - Ubuntu should have no problem doing this either (Unless you aren't in an UBUNTU with a GUI - that can be fixed with startx *IF SUPPORTED*)

b.) If you have to pull directly from the site itself, you could try something like this using BEAUTIFULSOUP from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863101/python-urllib-urlopen-not-working). Honestly, I've never really used the latter option since downloading and moving is much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the image as a `JPG`.

```py
import requests

img_url = "http://dimik.pub/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/javaWeb.jpg"

r = requests.get(img_url)

with open("java_book.jpg","wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a full HTML document:

[image: java_book.jpg]